# Delphi: How to respond to WM_SettingChange/WM_WinIniChange?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, message, delphi-5

i need to know when my application recieves a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497(v=VS.85).aspx) message (formerly known as [`WM_WININICHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725499(VS.85).aspx)).

Problem is that the message pump in **TApplication** sends it down a black hole (default handler) before i can get a chance to see it:

```
procedure TApplication.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
...
begin
   Message.Result := 0;

   for I := 0 to FWindowHooks.Count - 1 do
      if TWindowHook(FWindowHooks[I]^)(Message) then Exit;

   CheckIniChange(Message);

   with Message do
      case Msg of
      WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
         begin
            Mouse.SettingChanged(wParam);
            Default;   <----------------------*poof* down the sink hole
         end;
      ...
      end;
      ...
end;
```

The procedure `CheckIniChange()` doesn't throw any event i can handle, neither does `Mouse.SettingChanged()`.

And once the code path reaches `Default`, it is sent down the `DefWindowProc` drain hole, never to be seen again (since the first thing the WndProc does is set the `Message.Result` to zero.

i was hoping to assign a handler to a TApplicationEvents.OnMessage event:

```
procedure TdmGlobal.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   case Msg.message of
   WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
      begin
         // Code
      end;
   end;
end;
```

But the OnMessage event is only thrown for messages that come through the message pump. Since the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message is "handled", it never sees the

```
PeekMessage
TranslateMessage
DispatchMessage
```

system.

How can i respond to the windows broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit2: For older versions the usual message intercept should work...**

```
[...]
  private
    procedure WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange); message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
[...]
procedure TForm1.WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
begin
  showMessage('SettingChange message intercept');
end;
```

Edit: Ooops! Did not see it was for D5. **The following was in D2007+.**

Use an OnSettingChange in your Application:

```
procedure TApplication.SettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnSettingChange) then
    with Message do
      FOnSettingChange(Self, Flag, Section, Result);
end;
```

You can test with this code. Try and change the height or docking side of the TaskBar...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnSettingChange := MySettingChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.MySettingChange(Sender: TObject; Flag: Integer;
  const Section: string; var Result: Integer);
begin
  showMessage('setting changed');
end;
```

Comment: `Application.OnSettingChange` worked for me in D7.  I couldn't get the usual `...message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;` to work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was in my question, the dangerous, undocumented, use of `HookMainWindow`:

```
procedure TdmGlobal.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ...
   Application.HookMainWindow(SettingChangeHook);
end;

procedure TdmGlobal.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Application.UnhookMainWindow(SettingChangeHook);
end;

function TdmGlobal.SettingChangeHook(var Message: TMessage): Boolean;
begin
   case Message.Msg of
   WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
      begin
         //Handler code
      end;
   end;

   Result := False; //continue processing
end;
```

Comment: well, undocumented... http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TApplication.HookMainWindow

Answer (score 2):

You handle it just like you would any other message. TApplication's default handler will route it correctly if you set up a message handler for it:

```
// interface
type
  TYourMainForm = class(TForm)
    // other stuff
  private
    procedure WMSettingChange(var Msg: TWMSettingChange); message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
  end;

// implementation
procedure TYourMainForm.WMSettingChange(var Msg: TWMSettingChange); message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
begin
  // Whatever handling here. TWMSettingChange is defined in Messages.pas
end;
```

Comment: i didn't appreciate the fact that the message is broadcast to all my forms - i assumed it went only to the application's main message loop.